# When should a method be called with present vs past participle, i.e. sort vs sorted or reverse vs reversed?

Tags: scala, naming

Scala have mutable class [Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Array). It has methods `sorted` and `reverse` with of them returns new mutable array with same items in some order.

Are there some reason to have different forms for methods names? Why `sorted` is not named `sort`? Or why `reverse`, `sortBy` etc is not named `reversed`, `sortedBy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's historical.  Before collections were redone in 2.8, there was a method on some collections ([e.g. List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.4/scala/List.html#sort%28%28A%2CA%29%3D%3EBoolean%29)) called `sort`.  In 2.8, `sort` was deprecated and its functionality was put into `sortWith`, and `sorted` was added to be a no-explicit-parameter sort.

One could imagine a principled way to do it (e.g. use past tense when creating a new collection, but present when altering a mutable one), but that's not really how it works.  You just have to remember the little wrinkles, for now at least.